# Tournament graph shortest walk to special vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Tournament graph is a complete directed graph where each edge can be only one direction. How can I prove that there exists at least one vertex such that it can be reached from every other vertex either directly or passing through only one intermediary vertex.

Comment: What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Have only vague guess that this can be proved by induction and constrains on the number of edges and sum of vertex degrees.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. My comment doesn't apply. The extremal principle used by quasi works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $v\in V$, let

- $\text{out}(v)$ be the set of vertices $w$ such that there is a directed edge from $v$ to $w$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\text{in}(v)$ be the set of vertices $w$ such that there is a directed edge from $w$ to $v$.

Choose $v\in V$ with least outdegree, $a$ say.

**Claim:**$\;$For all $u\in V{\,\setminus}\{v\}$, there is a directed path of length at most $2$ from $u$ to $v$.

**Proof:**

Let $u\in V{\,\setminus}\{v\}$.

Let $A=\text{out}(v)$ and let $B=\text{in}(v)$.

First suppose $u\in B$.

Then there is a directed edge from $u$ to $v$, so there is a directed path of length $1$ from $u$ to $v$.

Next suppose $u\in A$.

If $\text{out}(u)\cap B={\large{\varnothing}}$, then $\text{out}(u)\subseteq A{\,\setminus}\{u\}$, which has cardinality less than $a$, contrary to the minimality of $a$.

Hence $\text{out}(u)\cap B\ne{\large{\varnothing}}$. Then letting $w\in \text{out}(u)\cap B$, it follows that $uwv$ is a directed path of length $2$ from $u$ to $v$.

This completes the proof.